# ODEX file: Does every app has one and if yes where are they stored?

Tags: file-system, odex

I know that `.odex` files are optimized .dex files.

I have seen a lot of `.odex` files below the path `/system` on my phone. I am just curious if there are also `.odex` files for my installed apps.

I searched the file system but I wasn't able to find `.odex` files for my installed apps. But I assume that they exist - the question is just where they are stored.

BTW: My phone is a rooted Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1.2

Comment: I think only prepackaged system apps will have .odex files because any other app isn't optimized specifically for your device, although I could be wrong on that.

Comment: `.odex` files make the app launch faster (on system boot).  Therefore they are only applicable for System-installed apps, not regular apps from the Play Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your ROM is booted up for the first time, Android's Dalvik goes through every apk and extracts the dex file from it.  It places the dex files in the cache folder - located at /data/dalvik-cache.  This is the directory that gets cleared when you clear the dalvik cache in your recovery tool

Comment: So Android generates odex files in /data/dalvik-cache only the first time you boot Android? Or the odex files are generated every boot if the cache is empty?

Comment: Are you sure these are `.odex` files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes every user app has an odex file. Check `/data/app` and you will see every user app with a folder called `oat` in that folder, in which you will see an odex file

Answer (score -1):

I believe every app has an ODEX db because this keeps the app files for running the app,the widget or apk cant work without it. Its normally located in the Secure file system under apps,each app with have its icon and the odex file with the same name .ODEX next to it.

Answer (score -1):

To know where `.odex` files ​are stored you can use a terminal emulator and run the following command:

```
su && find / -name=*.odex*
```